# Kernel SVM primal with Stochastic Gradient Descent

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

In short: I am currently reading Online Learning with Kernels (http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips14/AA33.pdf) for fun and I can't figure out how he got to equation 8 from equations 6 and 7.

The idea is: We want to minimize a risk function

```
$R_stoch\[f,t\]:=c(x_t,y_t,f(x_t))+\lambda\Omega\[f\]$
```

If we want apply the representer theorem on `f`, writing it as

```
$f(x)=\sum\alpha_i k(x,x_i)$
```

how can we get to the `STOCHASTIC` gradient descent update?

Answer (score 0):

A set of *k(x<sub>i</sub>, x)* seems to form a basis of *H*, and since *f* is in *H*, then *f* can be written as a linear combination of "kernel functions".

So pretending set of *k(x<sub>i</sub>, x)* forms a basis of *H*, it's obvious that if we have some linear combation of the left-hand side and another on the right-hand side, and they're equal, then their basis vector coefficients should be equal too (it's well-known fact from linear algebra that vector equality means vector coefficients (in the same basis!) equality).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, very illuminating.
There is one more thing that confuses me though.

Comment: How did they compute the derivative of ||f||^2 as f? As an example, again take f=sum_{i=1}^n a_i*k(x,x_i). Then ||f|||=<f,f>=sum_isum_ja_ia_jk(x_i,x_j)=transpose(A)*K*A where K is the gram matrix and A is the vector of coefficients. Then the derivative would be K*A+transpose(A)*K=2*K*A (a gradient vector). whereas simply f would be, in short, K_x*A (a number) where K_x is the xth row of the gram matrix.

Comment: Oh, it's so hard to read / write math formulas on SO… I've written smple derivation of gradient by definition in latex: [link](http://bit.ly/ZstmcN)

Comment: And about your arguments: if we choose an orthonormal basis, then derivative of ||f||^2 would be 2A where A is f :-) f is vector, since it lies in linear space (and is a linear combination of basis vectors).

Comment: Thank you very much again. I am still confused, in certain stages of the process. So I have written a (hopefully) more clear specification above.

Comment: Well it's not visible yet... so I've written in in the comments below. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Given the primal objective

    F(A)=(L*sum_{i,j}a_{i}*a_{j}*k(x_i,x_j) + sum_{i}max(0, 1-y_i sum_{j}a_j*k(x_i,x_j))

for the soft margin SVM, where

    A=(a_1,...,1_N)
N being the number of training examples.
I am trying to get the stochastic gradient descent update for A (vector of a_i). Again, consider <a href="http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips14/AA33.pdf">Online Learning with Kernels</a>. While it makes sense for the general case for a general f, I don't know how to adapt it here.

More specifically:
In the paper we have the general objective

    c(x_t, y_t, f(x_t)) + L*1/2*||f||^2

Comment: I understand that by taking the derivative with respect to f, we get to the update

    f=(1-L*r)*f - r*c'(x_t,y_t,f(x_t))*k(x_t,.)
Now in my case (soft margin/hinge loss kernel SVM) I don't really see how to apply that in order to get the updates for a_i. I mean, if I just go ahead and take the derivative of my initial F_n(A), I get 

    dF_n(A)/da_{i}=2*L*G*A - y_i*k(x_n,x_i)

so, actually I have consider the objective

  F_n(A)=(L*sum_{i,j}a_{i}*a_{j}*k(x_i,x_j) + max(0, 1-y_i sum_{j}a_j*k(x_i,x_j)

But... now what?... :-)

Comment: G is the gramm matrix. But I'm missing something, and I don't know what :)

Comment: I'm not quite follow you… I think SO isn't right place to ask such questions. Try math.stackexchange.com or mathoverflow.

Comment: Well let's just considerF(A)=(L*sum_{i,j}a_{i}*a_{j}*k(x_i,x_j) + sum_{i}max(0, 1-y_i sum_{j}a_j*k(x_i,x_j)) and try to get the SGD updates for A. That's the purpose of it all